# How do I turn in password saving in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I would like Chrome to save my passwords, but I do not know how to turn on that feature. I have not "tried" anything because I just started using Windows 10 and am not familiar enough with it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not affect Chrome usage.

Under Chrome - click on the burger(?) icon on the top right corner, and choose "Settings". Scroll to the bottom of the settings page and click on "Show Advanced Settings".

You should see a heading for "Password and Forms"

You just need to tick [x] Offer to save your web passwords.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings
2. Either you search "password" in search setting field or you can go to Show advanced settings.. in bottom of the page.
3. After that in Passwords and forms section:
   check the Offer to save web passwords.

Done now Chrome will ask any time you can enter a password to save or not.